# How to bring back the replication system in postgresql if the master ip address has been changed in ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, master-slave

Postgresql database replication has two servers one for master and the other for a slave. Due to some reason the master IP address got changed which was being used at several places in the slave server. With the new IP address, after replacing the old ones with the latest one in the slave server the replication is not working as before. Can someone help to resolve this issue?
Following are the steps used in setting up the slave server :

1.add the master IP address in the pg_hba.conf file for the user replication

```
nano /etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf host
    replication  master-IP/24  md5

2.modify the following lines in the PostgreSQL.conf file of slave server where listen_addresses should be the IP of the slave server
    nano /etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf
    listen_addresses = 'localhost,slave-IP'
    wal_level = replica
    max_wal_senders = 10
    wal_keep_segments = 64

3. Take the backup of the master server by entering the IP


pg_basebackup -h master-ip -D /var/lib/postgresql/11/main/ -P -U
    replication --wal-method=fetch

4.create a recovery file and adding the following commands


 standby_mode          = 'on'
    primary_conninfo      = 'host=master-ip port=5432 user=replication password= '
    trigger_file = '/tmp/MasterNow'
```

Below is the error from the log file:

```
started streaming WAL from primary at A/B3000000 on timeline 2
FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000020000000A000000B3 has already been removed

FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "master ip" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

record with incorrect prev-link 33018C00/0 at 0/D8E15D18
```

Answer (score 1):

The standby server was down long enough that the primary server does not have the required transaction log information any more.

There are three remedies:

1. set the `restore_command` parameter in the standby server's recovery configuration to restore WAL segments from the archive (that should be the inverse of `archive_command` on your primary server). Then restart the standby.

   This is the only option that allows you to recover without rebuilding the standby server from scratch.
2. Set `wal_keep_segments` on the primary server high enough that it retains enough WAL to cover the outage.

   This won't help you recover now, but it will avoid the problem in the future.
3. Define a *physical replication slot* on the primary and put its name in the `primary_slot_name` parameter in the standby server's recovery configuration.

   This won't help you recover now, but it will avoid the problem in the future.

   **Note:** When using replication slots, monitor the replication. Otherwise a standby that is down will lead to WAL segments piling up on the primary, eventually filling up the disk.

All but the first options require that you rebuild your standby with `pg_basebackup`, because the required WAL information is no longer available.

Comment: Thanks, Laurenz for the solution. Should I rebuild the standby server without altering anything? I mean I shouldn't delete the existing database all I have to do is pg_basebackup from the master server that will have all the data?
Correct me if I am missing something here on how to bring back standby server up

Comment: If you use archives like in my first solution, all you have to do is wait for the standby to catch up. With the other options, you have to stop the standby, remove the data directory and rebuild it from scratch with `initdb`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Laurenz. This helps!! Which one of these solutions do you suggest as the best one for a failure situation like this in the future?

Comment: I prefer 1 if there are archives, otherwise 3 if there is monitoring, otherwise 2.

Comment: This worked. I tried the solution of removing the data directory and ran pg_basebackup works like a charm as before. Laurenz can you please suggest which method of replication is best suitable for PostgreSQL to implement? (streaming or hot stand by or any other)

Comment: Hot standby is not replication. You want streaming replication, like you already have running.

Answer (score 0):

> host replication  master-IP/24  md5

This line is missing a field.  The USER field.

> listen_addresses = 'localhost,slave-IP'

It is rarely necessary for this to be anything other than '*'.  If you don't try to micromanage it, that is one less thing you will need to change.  Also, changing `wal_keep_segments` on the replica doesn't do much unless you are using cascading replication.  It needs to be changed on the master.

> pg_basebackup -h master-ip -D /var/lib/postgresql/11/main/ -P -U
>       replication --wal-method=fetch

Did this indicate that it succeeded?

> FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL
>   segment 000000020000000A000000B3 has already been removed
>
> FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: could not connect to
>   server: Connection timed out
>           Is the server running on host "master ip" and accepting
>           TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

This is strange.  In order to be informed that the file "has already been removed", it necessarily had to have connected.  But the next line says it can't connect.  It is not unusual to have a misconfiguration that prevents you from connecting, but in that case it wouldn't have been able to connect the first time.  Did you change configuration between these two log messages?  Is your network connection flaky?

Comment: Hi, janes. Yes, the connection issue is resolved now. The main blocker is with the WAL file, the standby server is not having the data which is lost during this downtime from the master server. How do we bring back the data from the master to the standby server?

Comment: Laurenz has covered the options for that pretty well.  Unless you have a WAL archive someplace with the missing WAL files, you will have to run pg_basebackup again.